# Stepinfo equivalent command for discrete response

Tags: matlab

If I have a discrete system, which matlab command should I use to get the system characteristics?

Isnt stepinfo command  for continuous systems??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stepinfo` works for both continuous and discrete systems. From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/stepinfo.html):

> `S = stepinfo(sys)` computes the step response characteristics for an
>   LTI model `sys` (see `tf`, `zpk`, or `ss` for details).

It doesn't say anything about the LTI model being continuous.